# Efficient way of writing child of parents in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

```js
var array = [
  {id: 1, name: "Father", parent_id: null},
  {id: 2, name: "Child", parent_id: 1},
  {id: 3, name: "Child", parent_id: 1},
  {id: 4, name: "ChildChild", parent_id: 2},
  {id: 5, name: "ChildChildChild", parent_id: 4}
]

  for(var i in array){
    if(array[i].parent_id == null){
       console.log(array[i].name);
    } else {
      for(var j in array){
          if(array[i].parent_id == array[j].id && array[j].parent_id == null){
              console.log(">" + array[i].name);
              for(var x in array){
                  if(array[i].id == array[x].parent_id){
                      console.log(">>" + array[x].name);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Father
>Child
>>ChildChild
>Child
```

I have this array which has id, name and parent_id. Right now it is fixed but it could have multiple arrays and can be nested for n amount of times.

What I am doing here is iterating through each array and trying to find which are the parents and which one is the child.

I want to know if there is a more efficient way to write this code. For instance, I added a fifth id but that would require another for loop and so on. The output would be the same just a printed out tree.

Comment: do you want to get a tree or a fastrer access to some node? please add the wanted result.

Comment: the wanted result is the same as my output but a more efficient way to write the code so that I could give any array and it would work. So basically just a tree.

Comment: can you. put at least one nested array inside your object, by. looking at your output  I dont' fully get your logic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Map` to key your nodes by id, and then use recursion to traverse them in depth first order:

```js
var array = [{id: 1, name: "Father", parent_id: null},{id: 2, name: "Child", parent_id: 1},{id: 3, name: "Child", parent_id: 1},{id: 4, name: "ChildChild", parent_id: 2},{id: 5, name: "ChildChildChild", parent_id: 4}];

let map = new Map(array.map(({id}) => [id, []])).set(null, []);
array.forEach(node => map.get(node.parent_id).push(node));
function dfs(nodes, indent="") {
    for (let node of nodes) {
        console.log(indent + node.name);
        dfs(map.get(node.id), indent+">");
    }
}
dfs(map.get(null));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a tree and then make the output.

```js
const
    print = ({ name, children = [] }) => {
        console.log(name)
        children.forEach(print);
    },
    array = [{ id: 1, name: "Father", parent_id: null }, { id: 2, name: "Child", parent_id: 1 }, { id: 3, name: "Child", parent_id: 1 }, { id: 4, name: "ChildChild", parent_id: 2 }, { id: 5, name: "ChildChildChild", parent_id: 4 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[o.parent_id] = t[o.parent_id] || {};
            t[o.parent_id].children = t[o.parent_id].children || [];
            t[o.parent_id].children.push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(array, null);

tree.forEach(print);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```